# How do I get Bzr to run an arbitrary command on commit

Tags: bazaar

I need the ability to run an arbitrary command when I try and commit to a bazaar branch.

This command should return 0 on success, or any other code on failure, and if the command fails, bzr should refuse to commit.

I want to do this for running test suites mainly, however, there are also other things (for example, checking whether there is a freeze on the branch that is trying to be committed, etc etc) that I'd like to be able to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a pre_commit hook, check for example:

http://schettino72.wordpress.com/category/testing/

Comment: *chuckles* I'd just found that blog link, and was coming back to add a link in to it to answer the question, when I saw this :D